# Is There a Way to Add a Search Bar or Something Similar to My Site That Does the same function as Ctrl+F?

Tags: html, web, browser

Just as the title says, I am trying to find out if there is a way to add a search bar or something to a few of my site's pages that would do the same thing that Ctrl+F does on Google Chrome or other browsers. A "find" function essentially for the entire page(s). One of my site's is a WordPress site so if it as simple as installing a specific plugin I may have missed, that'd be great too.

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough, there actually is *A "find" function essentially for the entire page*, it is even built-in in all browsers, and it is even called … `find`.

**[`window.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find)**

Big caveat: it was never standardized and probably is not exactly what you will use, since it really performs operation similar to Ctrl+F, so it moves focus to first and consecutive search match occurrences, so it probably is not usable for "find as you type".

```html
<input value="Hello"><button onclick="find(previousSibling.value)">Search</button>

<p>Hi, Hello, Bye!</p>
```

Comment: First off, thank you so much for the feedback and answer. This is very interesting to say the least and definitely progress towards what I am looking for. Going to tinker with it. Thank you so much. I am still new to html etc, can you post another version of this where you make the search bar larger? I believe it includes specifying how large I want it using px (pixel) size correct?